# "FromName" is not a member of "Gdiplus::Color"

Tags: c#, c++

I've been trying to take a screenshot in C++ for hours now. I finally managed to get it and save it to a JPG file but before that, I'd like to read the Bitmap created. I'm using the windows library. Here is a simple example where I try to do something with the Color class and it doesn't work. I'm using CodeBlocks on Windows 7.

```
Color slateBlue = Color::FromName( "SlateBlue" );
Byte g = slateBlue.G;
Byte b = slateBlue.B;
Byte r = slateBlue.R;
Byte a = slateBlue.A;
```

taken from here : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

When I compile that, I have this error :

`"FromName" is not a member of "Gdiplus::Color"`

Yes I linked my project to Gdiplus, so the problem is not coming from that.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I think I need to update GDI+

Comment: I believe the [GDI+ `Color` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534427(v=vs.85).aspx) is not the same class as `System.Drawing.Color`.

Comment: I'm new to this, you might be right, but then where's the doc of the GDI+ Color class ? (thanks)

Comment: Ok wait I'm reading the link you gave

Comment: Ok but that doesn't explain why the code doesn't work ? I included <windows.h>